# Is there any way to trigger AWS Lambda or SQS for every insert update and delete operation in any of the schemas of RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

I am figuring out if there is any way to trigger AWS Lambda or SQS for every insert update and delete operation in any of the schemas of RDS. DynamoDb provides DDB stream but don't have idea about RDS. Went through some blogs but not that ideafull.

Tried using plpgsql trigger but failed.

My use case is I am trying to create a separate audit table and record every events (insert update and delete) for analytics purpose.

Comment: If you are using Aurora: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. But I am using RDS PostgresSql not aurora PostgresSql

Comment: What is the typical usage of your database? If it is in the millions of transactions per hour/day/week then you may find that it is more cost effective to resort to traditional rdms auditing techniques.

Comment: @RossBush understood. But I don't have that huge traffic rt now.

Comment: I figured you were using RDS, but you should consider migrating to Aurora. I don't think what you want is possible with plain RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AWS DMS monitors RDS CDC and can target things such as S3 which can create cloudwatch SNS events you can listen for from SQS

Your SQS queue will receive reference to S3 which you can read the events out of like

I,1231231,32312312,SOMETHING

U,1231231,32132132,NOPE

Where I = insert, U = update